# Subjunctive in "Ce qui est important"?

Tags: grammaire, subjonctif

> Ce qui est important dans une relation, c'est que l'on ___ honnête l'un avec l'autre.

Should the indicative *est* or the subjunctive *soit* be used here? If the sentence were

> Il est important dans une relation que ...

then clearly the subjunctive is required. In our sentence the meaning is very similar to this, but the structure is different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

L'indicatif est utilisé chaque fois que l'on considère la réalité d'un fait.

Je **t'affirme** qu'il a trop de travail pour nous rejoindre

Le subjonctif est utilisé pour un fait envisagé mais non encore réel ni effectif.

Elle veut qu'on lui **rende** sa nouvelle poupée.

---

Dans ce cas, c'est un fait envisagé.

Ce qui est important dans une relation, c'est que l'on **soit** honnête l'un avec l'autre.

(http://www.francaisfacile.com/)

Comment: Donc, si ce n'est pas un fait envisagé, on doit utiliser l'indicatif ? Par exemple, *Ce qui est important, c'est que tu **as** réussi l'examen hier* (et pas **aies**)

Comment: L'indicatif est correct ici, mais en pratique, dans cas comme d'autres, il est fréquent d'entendre le subjonctif. Je ne saurais pas dire si c'est un légère déformation, ou une réelle erreur. Autre exemple, beaucoup de français diront "*Après qu'il ait fait ...*" alors que [la forme correcte](http://www.academie-francaise.fr/apres-que) est "*après qu'il a fait ...*", le subjonctif prend parfois la place de l'indicatif, ce qui rend le tout plus compliqué. D'ailleurs, les deux versions de ta phrase me vont, mais à l'inverse je dirais "*Le problème, c'est que tu **as** raté l'examen hier*"...