# Subjunctive in "J'admire que"?

Tags: grammaire, subjonctif

> J'admire qu'elle ___ travailler sans fatigue jusqu'à 22h tous les jours.

Should the indicative *peut* or the subjunctive *puisse* be used here? Normally the subjective is used for [*aimer* or *détester*](https://french.kwiziq.com/revision/grammar/aimer-que-detester-que-subjonctif-to-like-or-hate-that), so should that also be the case for *admirer*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"*J'admire que*" is not correct, even though some people might say it. You should say "*J'admire le fait que ...*", followed by subjunctive.

And you can't say "*sans fatigue*", say "*sans se fatiguer*" instead.

Comment: Is there a rule for the verbs which can't be followed by *que*? And are you sure the subjunctive is mandatory? Of course I'd instinctively use subjunctive, but I can't find a logical reason not to use present in such a case, since it's a generality (*elle peut travailler sans se fatiguer, et j'admire ça*).

Comment: [Another question](http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/23320/subjunctive-in-ce-qui-est-important) made me realize our use of subjunctive is almost random and not that justified... Every time I try to find a logical reason or a rule I find a example that shouldn't use subjunctive... I read recently that actually, we use subjunctive more than we should, sometimes incorrectly, so I feel like I don't know anything anymore...

Comment: I feel the same about subjunctive, it sounds better but when you ask: "why not present?", then it often ends with "both are correct".

Comment: Exactly. I can imagine the struggle for a learner... It has to comes with practice I guess.

Comment: I can only imagine too, since I'm French.